# Detect IVR question and return response using twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, ivr, twilio-node

Currently I am working on Twilio API. I need to call IVR number using twilio. 
IVR Number ask question. In Twilio using speech recognition i want to detect question and provide answer accordingly.

Something Like Need to activate mobile sim-card :-

=> Call to IVR Number (1900)

Question :- Enter your birth-date(Detect question in TWilio and pass answer)

Answer :- 1 January, 2001 (Answerd by Twilio)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio Autopilot for something like this.

[Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/autopilot)

[Twilio Autopilot You Tube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edViFb-A0zw&list=PLqrz4nXepkz7eH7EkSAcPhndANEmR9Uau)

Comment: Hello Alan, Could you provide me more resource where i can get more idea. because i want to do outgoing call and pass anwser on basis of IVR system asking.

Comment: You can use the Twilio Calls Resource to initiate an outbound call, pointing the URL portion to your Autopilot assistant URL (viewable under channels/Programmable Voice of your assistant) - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **return a response based on keypad activity in phone** then use this

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-node-js

and

if you want to **return a response based on voice input** then use this

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/build-interactive-voice-response-ivr-phone-tree

Happy coding!